# PHP - GET url encode @, \ and & sign

Tags: php, get, decode, encode

This PHP code:

```
$test = '@&\\';
echo rawurlencode($test);
```

Results in this:

```
http://example.com/test=%40%26%5C
```

Which in a $_GET request in a url becomes something like this:

```
test=@&\
```

The above is not an allowed $_GET variable.

How can I still use a $_GET variable with these values, encode them and decode them back to get these values?

Comment: use base64_encode('@&\\'); and on the other side use base64_decode('output');

Comment: *a url becomes something like this:* `... test=@&\ `.  It shouldn't be that way.   It should be `http://example.com?test=%40%26%5C`

Comment: @aman That worked for my case. Is it safe for every character?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I updated my question to not making it as confusing.

Comment: *"The above is not an allowed $_GET variable."* - Why?

Comment: Please ignore @aman, that's terrible and confused advice.

Comment: Browsers do a lot of things with the stuff you type in them, from adding `http://` to searching it in Google. That's nothing that affects your PHP code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*The URL* will most certainly be `http://example.com/test=%40%26%5C` if you create the URL as `http://example.com/test=%40%26%5C`. When PHP receives a request for this URL, PHP *automatically decodes* the query string and puts it into `$_GET`. *The URL* didn't change, you simply have the *decoded value* of the query string available to your PHP script in the `$_GET` variable.

Additionally the browser *may* decide to display the URL in a decoded form in the address bar for usability/readability. It does not mean that the *actual* URL contains `@&\` characters.

Comment: The final result is that I want to add a path to the url, like this: test=C:\some\path\with\a\file\filename@.txt. How would you do that without breaking anything?

Comment: `'http://example.com/?test=' . rawurlencode('C:\some\path\with\a\file\filename@.txt')` – That should do it just fine. On the receiving end, you just do `$_GET['test']` to get `C:\some\path\with\a\file\filename@.txt`.

Comment: Personally, I prefer [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) but it's pretty much the same thing

Comment: @Phil Absolutely agreed, I just wanted to stick to some basic primitives here to get the point across.

Comment: @deceze When I use that I get "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.". When I try some 'normal' url characters, letters and numbers it works.

Comment: @Jens That depends on how your server processes the request, or what else you're doing with that URL, which we obviously don't know.